# Download file symfony 5, can not take file with url, error 404 was not found on this server

Tags: file, download, symfony5

OrderController:

```
public function downloadExcelAction(string$filename):BinaryFileResponse

    {

        // Xác định đường dẫn đến file Excel trong thư mục /public/excel/

        // $filePath = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/excel/' . $filename;
        $filePath = realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/excel/' . $filename);


        // Kiểm tra xem file có tồn tại không

        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            throw new \Exception('File Excel không tồn tại.', 400);
        }

        // Tạo phản hồi cho file Excel
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);

        // Đặt tên file khi tải xuống
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $filename);

        return $response;
    }
```

and routers.yaml:

```
download_excel:

  path:       /api/order/download_excel/{filename}
  controller: App\Controller\OrderController::downloadExcelAction
  methods:    GET
```

and here terminal check the permissions on the file to make sure the server has permission to read.

```
export_order !4 ?2 ❯ ls -l ~/Desktop/CustomerApi/public/excel    

total 88
-rw-rw-rw-  1 masterhellcat  staff  42873 May 20 15:47 order_export_20230520084729.xlsx
```

and An error occurred while the file was created and linked correctly
Not Found
The requested resource /api/order/download_excel/order_export_20230520084729.xlsx was not found on this server.

i have tried to provide access to pc url and reference from multiple sources. I hope everyone can help me improve the code so that it works properly to download files or also help me solve the server file access problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer

```
public function downloadExcelAction(Request $request): BinaryFileResponse
    {
        $filename = $request->query->get('file');
        
        // Xác định đường dẫn đến file Excel trong thư mục /public/excel/
        $filePath = realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/excel/' . $filename);

        
        // Kiểm tra xem file có tồn tại không
        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            throw new \Exception('File Excel không tồn tại.', 400);
        }

        // Tạo phản hồi cho file Excel
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);

        // Đặt tên file khi tải xuống
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $filename);

        return $response;
    }
```

and router

```
download_excel:
  path:       /api/order/download_excel
  controller: App\Controller\OrderController::downloadExcelAction
  methods:    GET
  requirements:
        filename: ".+.xlsx"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).